# Не изменяется цвет фона блока с помощью :hover

Tags: css, вёрстка, hover

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты! Я еще совсем зеленый в верстке, посему прошу Вашей помощи в решении проблемы с версткой макета.

По ТЗ при наведении на пункт верхнего меню, цвет фона меняется на более светлый, но у меня смена через `:hover` не срабатывает. Не срабатывает т.к. в спокойном состоянии фон залит градиентом, если его убрать, то `:hover` начинает работать.

И еще одна проблема, с изменением размера меню. Если начать сужать страницу -
 пункты меню перекидываются вниз, как и нужно, но все равно остается тень от тега ul.

Меню по ссылке - http://jsbin.com/faxiqakora/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

## Смена цвета при ховере

Используйте свойство `background` вместо `background-color` - тогда оно перекроет `background-image`, и вы увидите изменения при ховере.

## Тень при сужении меню

Тень оставалась, потому что у контейнера была задана фиксированная высота, равная высоте пунктов в один ряд.

Можно расположить пункты меню не флоатами, а инлайн-блоками. Тогда контейнер без дополнительных манипуляций будет принимать корректную высоту.

```css
.top-menu-list {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(170, 3, 22) 0%, rgb(203, 24, 44) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(170, 3, 22) 0%, rgb(203, 24, 44) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(170, 3, 22) 0%, rgb(203, 24, 44) 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.top-menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-menu-link {
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 52px;
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  border-right: 1px solid #df4242;
  border-left: 1px solid #df4242;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(170, 3, 22) 0%, rgb(203, 24, 44) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(170, 3, 22) 0%, rgb(203, 24, 44) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(170, 3, 22) 0%, rgb(203, 24, 44) 100%);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top-menu-link:hover {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-menu">
  <ul class="top-menu-list">
    <li class="top-menu-item"><a href='#' class="px-18 f-white top-menu-link">Компания</a></li>
    <li class="top-menu-item"><a href='#' class="px-18 f-white top-menu-link">Каталог</a></li>
    <li class="top-menu-item"><a href='#' class="px-18 f-white top-menu-link">Новости</a></li>
    <li class="top-menu-item"><a href='#' class="px-18 f-white top-menu-link">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li class="top-menu-item"><a href='#' class="px-18 f-white top-menu-link">Заявка</a></li>
    <li class="top-menu-item"><a href='#' class="px-18 f-white top-menu-link">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за background) Но с изменением размера меню не совсем понятно, в предложенном Вами варианте, получается что не только тень остается, но и кусок фона.

Comment: Верно, в вашем примере поведение такое же - контейнер растянут на всю ширину экрана, а так как у элементов ширина фиксированная - бывают моменты, когда они не полностью заполняют ширину контейнера, и сбоку остается фон и тень.